# Postgresql: How to delete entries in table_1 which have no match in table_2

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have two tables:

`"table_1"` with `columns "user_id","username","age"`
and
`"table_2"` with `columns "m_id","username","message"`

Now some users are not present anymore,
so I want to delete every entry in `"table_2"` which contain a `"username"` which is not in `"table_1"`

Does the following command work in POSTGRESQL?

```
DELETE FROM table_2 WHERE username NOT IN 
(SELECT username FROM table_1 WHERE username IS NOT NULL)
```

Do I need the `WHERE username IS NOT NULL` at the end of the command?

Following command did the trick:

```
DELETE FROM table_2 t2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM table_1 t1 
 WHERE t1.username = t2.username);
```

Comment: You probably don't but it won't hurt to leave it.

Comment: Better keep it. If you remove it and there is a single NULL username in table_1 then no record will be deleted from table_2 ever (this may never happen if table_2 has a `not null` constraint on username). However I like the approach of @JimJones better, it is more or less idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about `NULL` values, use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM table_2 t2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM table_1 t1 
 WHERE t1.username = t2.username);
```

Comment: lets say there is another table_3 which has entries which contain a reference to the table_2 entries. How to delete them in advance?

Comment: @midi use a nested query with a `RETURNING`. To get more details you'll have to post another question

Comment: I heard about "CASCADE" with this row(s) referencing it should be automatically deleted as well.  Or is that the wrong approach?

Comment: @midi if you can afford recreating the tables or adjusting your foreign keys, cascade is definitely the best option. cheers

Comment: I just found out that the query takes very long time if there are a lot of entries, like 10M.